# Cannot reach server on iOS device but simulator works

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, alamofire

I have my server written in Nodejs and express, last steps are like this:

```
server = app.listen(3000, function() { 
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000...\n");
});
```

I have my swift code like this (with my actual IP address):

```
Alamofire.request("http://123.123.123.123:3000", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .response(completionHandler: completionHandler)
```

This will get me a response on the simulator, also works with browser (from another computer). But on my actual iPhone this would always time out and never give any response. I have

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

in my `info.plist`, I am not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the iPhone has no route to the server

Comment: Good guess, what do I do?

Comment: without knowing the network infrastructure involved, I guess you have to "do your best" - seriously, is the server on a local subnet, behind NAT? is the iphone on the same local subnet? is the server on local, but the iPhone on "public"? this appears to be a networking issue rather than a coding one

Comment: I doubt it, substituting my IP address with www.google.com then my phone can actually get the result, but substituting the IP address with my AWS instance running the same server would still time out, so I don't think it's a networking problem per se

Comment: so, the server is a public (internet) reachable resource?

Comment: Yes, the weirdest thing is that another server written in almost the same way can work, but not this one